# How to enumerate default groups for a user?

Tags: active-directory, adsi

**Default groups** of a user are not mentioned in memberOf attribue in active directory.

Can anyone tell how to retrieve these group for a user?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "default groups"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of Default Group in AD it looks like you are referring to primaryGroup.  If thats the case here is how to get it

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297951